# if dinamico con arrays php

Tags: condiciones

Hola estimados tengo la siguiente duda, tengo 2 arrays que se comparan pero son dinamicos, no siempre traen los mismos datos como puedo hacer un `if` con estos datos.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data) ; $i++) { 
$existe = false;
    for ($k=0; $k < count($result) ; $k++) { 
        if
        ( 
            ($data[$i]['OCP_ERP'] == $result[$k]['OCP_ERP']) && 
            ($data[$i]['N_INVOICE'] == $result[$k]['N_INVOICE'])
        )
        {
            $existe = true;
        }
    }

 }
```

El problema es que dentro del `if` comparo el array `$data` y `$result`, pero el array `$data` es dinamico (pero siempre va a tener los mismos valores que `$result` para comparar), como hago para que el `if` sea dinamico.

Comment: **"(pero siempre va a tener los mismos valores que $result para comparar)"** si siempre son iguales no hay necesidad de comparar.

Comment: me refiero a los indices ['OCP_ERP'] o ['N_INVOICE']